# What exactly classNameBindings is doing?

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember and I'm following a tutorial which contains code for component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['editing'],
  editing: false,
  actions: {
    editTodo() {
      this.toggleProperty('editing');
    }
  }
});
```

I don't understand what `classNameBindings` is doing. From documentation I've learned that `classNameBindings is a list of properties of the view to apply as class names`, but I also have `editing` property on the component. How existence of this property effects this process of creating `class names`?

Thank you for any help :-)

Comment: The explanation here seems perfectly coherent: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`classNameBindings` has two modes of usage. You can either toggle the class on/off, or you can add/omit classes based on the value of a property.

Toggle the class on an off:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['editing']
});
```

- `this.set('editing', true)` adds the `editing` CSS class to the element
- `this.set('editing', false)` removes the `editing` CSS class from the element

Add/omit classes based on the value of a property:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['editing:is-editing:not-editing']
}
```

- `this.set('editing', true)` adds the `is-editing` CSS class to the element
- `this.set('editing', false)` adds the `not-editing` CSS class to the element

You can omit either the true (`[editing::not-editing]`) or the false (`[editing:is-editing]`) branches. You can consult the [Customizing a Component's Element guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-class-names) and the [`classNameBindings`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember._MetamorphView.html#property_classNameBindings) API documentation for more details.

Comment: great explanation, that's what I was looking for

Comment: So, just to make it clear. In my case `editTodo` event handler adds or removes `editing` class from `li` element. That's correct ?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `classNameBindings: ['isEditing']` adds or removes the class named `is-editing`.

Comment: @torazaburo this behavior by default or I should provide some instructions to Ember.js

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that if the property is string-valued, that value is inserted as the class name.

Comment: @torazaburo true, I didn't want to repeat the documentation too much so I linked to both places I know that document all the behaviours.

Comment: I wonder if Embers's `classNameBindings` might have also been named `conditionalClassNames` as they are conditionally added to the component.